# cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When trying to import 'backend' from tensorflow.keras by the following line:

`from tensorflow.keras import backend`

I receive the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils'`

I could not find any solution online. Any idea what's going wrong here and how to fix it?

Technical specifications:

Windows 10
Python version 3.9.12
tensorflow version 2.10.0
keras version 2.10.0

Answer (score 1):

There could be an issue with how you installed TensorFlow in your system as importing this above API with the same given configuration, does show any error to me.

Please install the TensorFlow using this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) and try running the above code again. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Please check the replicated code snippet below:
[image]